# How to transpose row to multiple coloumn?

Tags: java, mysql

Look, I have this as data in mySQL . The table name is "schedule"

> ======================================================
>
> Mapel|Kelas|Tanggal| Nama| Status
>
> ======================================================
>
> Bhs. Indo  || 1A || 2015-01-14 || Adi || x
>
> Bhs. Indo  || 1A || 2015-01-14 || Ani || x
>
> Bhs. Indo  || 1A || 2015-01-14 || Sisi || -
>
> Bhs. Indo  || 1A || 2015-01-14 || Tara || -
>
> Bhs. Indo  || 1A || 2015-01-14 || Wina || x
>
> Math   || 1A || 2015-01-15 || Adi || x
>
> Math  || 1A || 2015-01-15 || Ani || -
>
> Math  || 1A || 2015-01-15 || Sisi || -
>
> Math  || 1A || 2015-01-15 || Tara || -
>
> Math  || 1A || 2015-01-15 || Wina || x
>
> Bhs. Indo   || 1A || 2015-01-15 || Adi || x
>
> Bhs. Indo   || 1A || 2015-01-15 || Ani || -
>
> Bhs. Indo  || 1A || 2015-01-15 || Sisi || -
>
> Bhs. Indo  || 1A || 2015-01-15 || Tara || -
>
> Bhs. Indo  || 1A || 2015-01-15 || Wina || x

Now I want to make a show a table depend on "MAPEL" and "KELAS"
if I chose Mapel = 'Bhs. Indo' and KELAS = '1A' would show a table like this

> ======================================================
>
> Kelas| Nama | 2015-01-14 | 2015-01-15 |
>
> ======================================================
>
> 1A || Adi || x  || x
>
> 1A || Ani || x  || -
>
> 1A || Sisi || - || -
>
> 1A ||Tara || -  || -
>
> 1A || Wina || x || x

Comment: did you make an attempt?

Comment: If it's indeed just 2 columns - use `CROSS-TAB`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically fetch dates based on the actual content in the table the only possible way to do it MySQL is to use dynamic SQL

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
  'MAX(CASE WHEN tanggal = ''', tanggal, 
  ''' THEN status END) `', tanggal, '`'))  
  INTO @sql
  FROM schedule 
 WHERE mape = 'Bhs. Indo'
   AND kelas = '1A'
 ORDER BY tanggal;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
  'SELECT kelas, nama, ', @sql, 
  '  FROM schedule ',
  ' WHERE mape = ''Bhs. Indo''',
  '   AND kelas = ''1A''',
  ' GROUP BY kelas, nama'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
| KELAS | NAMA | 2015-01-14 | 2015-01-15 |
|-------|------|------------|------------|
|    1A |  Adi |          x |          x |
|    1A |  Ani |          x |          - |
|    1A | Sisi |          - |          - |
|    1A | Tara |          - |          - |
|    1A | Wina |          x |          x |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/158ce/4)** demo

You can wrap it in a stored procedure to simplify things in your client code.